# Get one row to multiple order id and multiple product rows from json

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

Table "**Orders**":

| orderId | products |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | [{"title":"product1","amount":2,"price":5.60},{"title":"product2","amount":1,"price":3.29}] |

Expected Output:

| orderId | title | amount | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | product1 | 2 | 5.60 |
| 12345 | product2 | 1 | 3.29 |

I managed to get this far:

```
with products_array as (
    select json_array_elements(products #> '{}')
    from Orders
)
select products_array.json_array_elements #>> '{title}'  as title,
       products_array.json_array_elements #>> '{amount}' as amount,
       products_array.json_array_elements #>> '{price}'  as price,
from products_array
```

| title | amount | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product1 | 2 | 5.60 |
| product2 | 1 | 3.29 |

But I can't figure out how to add "*orderId*" for each line.

Can someone help in that regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract your json objects using [`JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), then use a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` to associate them to the corresponding "*orderid*".

```
SELECT orderid, 
       prods ->> 'title'  AS title,
       prods ->> 'amount' AS amount,
       prods ->> 'price'  AS price
FROM tab
CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(tab.products) as prods;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmX2j5eLTF11EgAQYhNHsj/0).

Comment: should it be `FROM Orders`?

Comment: yes, from Orders, I changed it already. THANK YOU, it works! You made my day!